# Autobiographer badge is buggy

Tags: bug, badges

I don't know whether it is just this site, but at least I have come across many SE sites that follow the specification stated below. According to ["Autobiographer" Badge now only requires sharing what YOU want with the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit), as well as the description of the badge on TEX.SX, one only need to fill in the "About me" section to get the badge. However the other day I tried to fill in that field in various ways and I didn't get the badge until I filled in all the fields of that form, which seems to be the behavior before the change in the linked question occured.

Comment: Badge awarding script is done periodically, not instantly though.

Comment: I see. So it may just be coincidence that when I filled in all the fields the script is executed and the badge is awarded.